# Finding the complete predicate

Tags: predicate

I am having trouble understand why the first part of the sentence provided is part of the complete predicate?

> From the Appalachian Mountains, the land falls gradually to great
>   river valleys to the west.

Comment: I'd venture that it's because *From ... Mountains* is adverbial in indicating where the falling begins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rearrange the sentence to put the subject-verb-(object) in it's normal place:

> The land **falls** gradually from the Appalachian Mountains to great river valleys to the west.

In the above, the complete predicate is *falls gradually from the Appalachian Mountains to great river valleys to the west.*